# Cookie value to define style on page load

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using the scripts from here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html and have successfully created a cookie.. it is set based on the users response to the age drop down.  However I am having trouble doing anything with it.  I would like to have a style defined if a cookie is present. Here is the bulk of my scripts..

```
function createCookie(name,value,days){
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function checkAge(){
    var min_age = 13;
    var year = parseInt(document.forms["emailForm"]["year"].value);
    var month = parseInt(document.forms["emailForm"]["month"].value) - 1;
    var day = parseInt(document.forms["emailForm"]["day"].value);
    var theirDate = new Date((year + min_age), month, day);
    var today = new Date;

    if ( (today.getTime() - theirDate.getTime()) < 0) {
        var el = document.getElementById('emailBox');
        if(el){
            el.className += el.className ? ' youngOne' : 'youngOne';
        }
        document.getElementById('emailBox').innerHTML = "<style type=\"text/css\">.formError {display:none}</style><p>Good Bye</p><p>You must be 13 years of age to sign up.</p>"; 
        createCookie('age','not13',0)
        return false;
    }
    else {
        createCookie('age','over13',0)
        return true;
    };
};

window.onload=function(){
   var x = readCookie('not13');
   if (x)  {    
        document.getElementById('emailBox').innerHTML = "<style type=\"text/css\">.formError {display:none}</style><p>Good Bye</p><p>You must be 13 years of age to sign up.</p>"; 
   }
}
```

Age verification works and cookie is set.... no errors (from Firebug).. can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.. I was looking for the cookie value and needed to look for the name and then create an if statement based on the value.  so..

```
 var x = readCookie('age');
if (x=='not13')  {    
   document.getElementById('emailBox').innerHTML = "<style type=\"text/css\">.formError {display:none}</style><p>Good Bye</p><p>You must be 13 years of age to sign up.</p>"; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

with [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) would be something like this

```
if (x) {
    var style =  "<style type=\"text/css\">.form {display:none}</style>";
    $("header").append(style);
}
```

Comment: well.. i was trying to do this without jQuery but I will give it a go.. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it should work. There's nothing incorrect about it.

The only thing I would suggest is that instead of injecting a **style** tag into a empty **div**, inject a **link** tag into the **head**. This will mean that your css changes and maintainance won't need to touch the js code.

Comment: Do you have a element on the page with an id="div"?

Comment: i updated my example with my actual code so it may make more sense now

Comment: what do you get when you alert(x)?